# Selecting the whole of a textbox once a option is clicked in a dropdown list

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to make a form for people to fill out. There is dropdown list that people click on to choose options. One of the options is "Other" which will activate a textbox to be able to free write what they want in. To make it easier and more obvious as to where they need to write it in I would like the text that is originally in the textbox to be selected so they do not have select all the text in there and then delete it.

I have some code that I thought would work but does not seem to work all the time. Once I have done the code it will work for a couple of time but then not work.

The code that I have is:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
If ComboBox1.Value = "Other" Then
   MsgBox "Please Specify below"
   TextBox1.Enabled = True
   TextBox1.Select
ElseIf ComboBox1.Value <> "Other" Then
   TextBox1.Enabled = False
   TextBox1.Value = "Please Specify"
End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work with ActiveX Controls now ;)

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
If ComboBox1.Text = "Other" Then
    MsgBox "Please Specify below"
    With TextBox1
        .Enabled = True
        .Select
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(.Text)
    End With
Else
   TextBox1.Enabled = False
   TextBox1.Text = "Please Specify"
End If
End Sub
```

It selects `TextBox1` and then selects as many characters there are in `TextBox1.Text`

Comment: Hello, Thank you for looking at it. It comes up with an error saying 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

Comment: It works for me in Word 365, does the code compile or it breaks while running it ? EDIT : my bad, i assumed you were using a Userform, but I guess you are not. I'm looking into it

Comment: It breaks whilst running. It accepts the code in the VBA editor tab but when I try and actually use it, it breaks.

Comment: You may try again